# Optimization constraints for types of oil

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, constraints

I'm looking at a lecture online which shows the following problem [image]

They have two types of oil and they want to produce standard and premium gasoline. However i'm confused how they've arrived at the constraints $2x_1+6x_2 \geq h_1$ and $3x_1+3x_2 \geq h_2$ and this was not explained in the lecture just skipped over. Surely if $h_1$ is the demand for standard gasoline with $x_1$ units of national oil the most we could make is $x_1/2$ units of standard gasoline and likewise $x_2/6$ with imported oil but they have $2x_1$ and $6x_2$. Also why are they being added together? Could someone explain the derivation of the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for comment.

Your confusion is valid, the constraint $2x_1+6x_2\ge h_1$ does not make sense. Say, $x_1=2$ units of national oil, $x_2=6$ units of imported oil and the demand for standard gas is $h_1=40$. The constraint is satisfied, however, with the given input ($x_1=2,x_2=6$) it can be produced only $1$ unit of standard gas.

I assume the decision variables should be units of output (standard and premium gas), not input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems these two constraints are still the problem definition. As mentioned, for standard gasoline you need 2 and 6 units of x1 and x2 (oils) respectively, and since the demand for standard gasoline is h1, the production must be equal or greater than that.

Comment: Ok so it's more just the problem definition than something that can be derived